# Get rid of navigation in angular material stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of the navigation in angular material stepper? I got it to work with horizontal stepper but with the vertical stepper it doesn't seem to work.

For removing the horizontal navigation:

```
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
  display: none !important;
}
```

But this code doesn't work with this vertical stepper could someone help out?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Vertical stepper** you need to assign different classes.

For removing the stepper header set below style.

```
.mat-vertical-stepper-header {
  display: none !important;
}
```

And removing the border set below style.

```
.mat-stepper-vertical-line::before { 
  border: 0 !important;
}
```